# Using Transactions - Best practices

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions

Assuming that I have a procedure in `SQL` Server as:

```
create procedure BULKINSERT
AS
 INSERT INTO TABLEB (
 SELECT NAME, ID From TableA
)
GO
```

A simple one which reads data from **`TABLE A`** and insert into **`TABLE B`**. If I have 1 million records to be inserted into table B and if one record fails for whatever reason , in this scenario should I use **`TRANSACTION`** or not ?

Should I rollback the entire operation?

Comment: use `TRY CATCH` with transactions

Comment: Since one **statement** is always considered atomic, and you have only 1 statement here, either 1 million records is inserted into `TABLEB` or none are. However, you might want to handle the error if it occurs in which case you should put your `INSERT` into a `TRY` block and add a `CATCH` one to handle what to do in case of error.

Comment: @MK_ You are correct. You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following template for your stored procedures:

```
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        -- CODE BLOCK GOES HERE
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 

       IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
       BEGIN
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
       END;

       -- GET ERRORS DETAILS OR THROW ERROR

    END CATCH;

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

More details:

- [XACT_ABORT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - specifies whether SQL Server automatically rolls back the current transaction when a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error;
- if you need information about the error ([ERROR_MESSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-message-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), ERROR_LINE, ERROR_NUMBER, ERROR_PROCEDURE, ERROR_SEVERITY, ERROR_STATE)

This is a general technique for working with transactions. I would recommend the following articles of `Erland Sommarskog`:

1. [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server
   Part One – Jumpstart Error Handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)
2. [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server
   Part Two – Commands and Mechanisms](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since one **statement** is always considered atomic, and you have only 1 statement here, either 1 million records is inserted into `TABLEB` or none are. However, you might want to handle the error if it occurs in which case you should put your `INSERT` into a `TRY` block and add a `CATCH` one to handle what to do in case of error.

To read up more on the subject, check the following sources for good starting points:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql
- http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions
- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3305/what-does-begin-tran-rollback-tran-and-commit-tran-mean/

Answer (score 2):

As stated a single statement is a transaction.

Sort the insert on the primary key of TABLEB to slow down fragmentation.

One thing to be careful of is inserting the same data multiple times.
If you want to prevent that then left join on a pk.

```
declare @Ta table (id int identity primary key, name varchar(10));
declare @Tb table (id int          primary key, name varchar(10));
insert into @Ta values ('name'), ('name'), ('name'), ('name'), ('name'), ('name'), ('name'), ('nameL');

insert into @Tb (id, name)
select id, name from @Ta order by id;

select * from @Tb;

insert into @Tb (id, name)
select ta.id, ta.name 
from @Ta ta 
left join @Tb tb 
  on tb.id = ta.id 
where tb.id is null 
order by ta.id;

select * from @Tb;
```

If you want to update data that is present search on the merge command.